# About important hacks in history

Tags: cryptography, authentication, file-encryption, authorization

I would like to know how important hacks happened, because I can figure out how they hacked a website but I can't figure out how did they hacked into NASA International Space Station source code. Or that information was explicitly passed through the NASA website? Any general information would be very much appreciated about this or any important hack, and I believe most of the community would also like to know about that.
EDIT: In a more general case I want to know how they hacked a computer without actually knowing where it is(eg. IPs, domain names or Wi-fi). The remaining steps are basically explainable, like buffer overflows, SQL Injections, decryption or any other specific tactic.

Comment: This is too broad.  I suggest editing the question and title to be solely about the NASA hack.  Also, please provide a link to information about the NASA hack (or cite other sources).

Comment: Or maybe leave the question general but make it comunnity wiki?

Answer (score 4):

You will probably be interested in Wikipedia's [Timeline of computer security hacker history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_computer_security_hacker_history).